# FormatDate issue with added time

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am having an issue with formatting a date field into a 24 hour time. Below is the FormatDate function I have in my AMPscript. My expected result would be to look like this: 19/05/2020 19:00 - 20:00

My string in the email looks like so:

%%=v(@EventStartDate)=%% - %%=v(@EventEndDate)=%%

My EventStartDate value from my data extension is 5/19/2020 7:00:00 PM
My EventEndDate value from the same data extension is 5/19/2020 8:00:00 PM

```
SET @EventStartDate = FormatDate(@EventStartDate,"dd/MM/YYYY","HH:mm tt","pt-BR")
SET @EventEndDate = FormatDate(@EventEndDate,"HH:mm")
```

However, when tested in the preview of my records I am getting this result: 19/05/2020 19:00 - 20:05

For some reason it seems to be adding in 5 minutes. Is there something I am missing or have formatted incorrectly?

This is the entire AMPscript in the email:

```
%%[
Var @EventName, @EventStartDate, @EventID, @FirstName, @SubscriberKey, @EventEndDate 
SET @SubscriberKey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey") 
SET @EventID = Lookup("ContactToOnlineEvent","Event ID","uuid",@SubscriberKey) 
SET @EventName = Lookup("OnlineEvent","Event Name","Event ID",@EventID) 
SET @EventStartDate = Lookup("OnlineEvent","Event start date","Event ID",@EventID)
SET @EventEndDate = Lookup("OnlineEvent","Event end date","Event ID",@EventID)
SET @FirstName = Lookup("ContactToOnlineEvent","First Name","uuid",@SubscriberKey)
SET @EventStartDate = FormatDate(@EventStartDate,"dd/MM/YYYY","HH:mm tt","pt-BR")
SET @EventEndDate = FormatDate(@EventEndDate,"HH:mm")

]%%
```

Comment: I think it might be because FormatDate separates the Date and Time parts. Try doing: `FormatDate(@EventEndDate,'','HH:mm')` and see if that works. Or could change to `Format(@EventEndDate,'HH:mm')`. (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatDate.htm)

Comment: @EventEndDate,'','HH:mm' worked! Thank you for the quick response. It is now showing the time in the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Moving from Comment to Answer for easier reference:**

I think it might be because [FormatDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatDate.htm) separates the Date and Time parts in the function:

[image]

If you set the function like this: `FormatDate(@EventEndDate,'','HH:mm')` it should remove the time changes. I am not sure why this happens, but it seems putting any time formats inside the 'date' part changes the time value by a few minutes.

Another way to get around this issue is you could change to [Format()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Format.htm) instead. Like: `Format(@EventEndDate,'HH:mm')`